# Adding Call Tracking Conversion Code To GTM

Tags: google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

Can I add an AdWords Conversion Code action type Call Tracking code to Google Tag Manager? This code tracks how many people click to the website from an ad and call the business number (google forwarding number).

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote an article on adding [call conversions to GTM](https://www.redflymarketing.com/blog/adwords-call-tracking-guide-gtm/) on Friday.

You'l need to add a custom HTML tag to the container to place some JS in.

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
(function(a,e,c,f,g,b,d){var h={ak:"996234153",cl:"RguGCL6AgVYQqaeF2wM"};a1=a1||function(){(a1.q=a1.q||[]).push(arguments)};a[f]||(a[f]=h.ak);b=e.createElement(g);b.async=1;b.src="//www.gstatic.com/wcm/loader.js";d=e.getElementsByTagName(g)[0];d.parentNode.insertBefore(b,d);a._googWcmGet=function(b,d,e){a1(2,b,h,d,null,new Date,e)}})(window,document,"_googWcmImpl","_googWcmAk","script");
// ]]></script>
```

You'll also need jQuery to add the number dynamically wherever you need it.